# Cpanel to hosting a web page Vue 3 (Vuetify)

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, vuetify.js, cpanel

I'm relatively new in the world of web hosting, and in my first job, I've been tasked with using a Cpanel to host a billing page. I've been considering using Vuetify along with possibly an API (maybe developed in Spring Boot) for connecting to the database. Is it possible to host these technologies on Cpanel?

Any insights or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

If hosting these technologies is possible, do you have any recommendations or tutorials on how to do it?

If it's not possible, could you recommend some alternative technologies for this development?

Comment: What do you mean by "using a Cpanel", exactly?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.